# Cross-process interaction under C++

Tags: c++, windows, interaction, cross-process

Please help, how can I organize the process-process data exchange (in Windows, if that matters)?

I have `process1.exe` which calls `process2.exe` with a few command line arguments. I want to track "progress" of `process2` from `process1` (say, some `int` value). It (that `int` value) can be accessed from `process1` permanently or each X ms - doesn't matter.

Will be useful any solution: WinApi or Qt.

Thank you everybody! All answers are very useful! :) Many thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OTOH:

- stdin/stdout redirection
- Named pipe (CreateNamedPipe)
- Anonymous pipe (CreatePipe)
- Sockets (socket, connect, bind)
- Shared memory (CreateFileMapping, MapViewOfFile)
- Windows messages (e.g. WM_APP)

Pick one - Windows messages or shared memory may be the easier ones.

Answer (score 4):

There are many options here:

1. You can redirect the standard output of process2 and have it output updates however often you like
2. If stdout is being used for something else, you can use a [named pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590%28VS.85%29.aspx) between the processes
3. You can also use [named shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will require less overhead and probably be easier to implement (the downside is that you may need to also do cross-process synchronization)
4. If process1 is running a message pump, then you can also use normal Windows messages (look at WM_COPYDATA)

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods:

- Sockets
- Messages
- Shared Memory (files)

The issue is that Process2 will be broadcasting and Process1 will be listening.  Process1 will need to know when Process2 is finished and maybe the percentage complete.

I believe Sockets would be the better route, but that depends on the application, development schedule and familiarity of concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send messages with Windows Api (SendMessage).

Answer (score 1):

An obvious omission in the options presented so far is COM. I'm expecting the usual flurry of "COM is crap" responses, but in my experience this hasn't been the case.

Comment: +1. And in extension of COM also DCOM across computers (which is also a form of IPC).